# Why do chrome devtools show font-size struck out in :root when it is also set in other elements?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, font-size

Here's the snippet, where I set `font-size` to 28 pixels in the `:root` ruleset (<s>by the way, is this something I should avoid? Should I set `font-size` on `body` or somewhere else?</s> see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990716/using-rem-to-set-font-size-inside-root-element-works-why))

```css
:root {
    font-size: 28px;
}
.fourteen {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.onerem {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="onerem">
    Ciao
  </div>
  <div class="fourteen">
    Ciao
  </div>
</div>
```

On the one hand, inspecting the page, I see the `onerem` class is given a `font-size` of 28 pixels, which proves that `font-size: 28px;` is in place.

On the other hand, I also see that from the CSS perspective, `font-size: 1rem;` is throwing away `:root`'s `font-size: 28px;`. Indeed, if I change `:root` to `.outer`, then both `Ciao`s are 14 pixels (assuming the browser's default is 14 pixels).

So where's the truth?

Probably [this answer is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991026/5825294), but one question imho stays: Chrome devtools show that `font-size: 28px;` is overriden by the other rules (see image below); but if it really was... how could it affect the meaning of `1rem`?

[image]

Comment: `rem` = size of font on the root node so you **reuse** it in `onerem`, not throw it away.

Comment: Oh, ok, so Chrome is correct, in a way. As in, the CSS rule `font-size: 28px;` is overriden for real, but the one that overrides, `font-size: 1rem;`, will still use the same value that was computed in `:root`?